# C#: Average From Series of Images

Tags: c#, drawing

Suppose I have a series of black and white images, NOT grayscale.  I'm trying to calculate an average of all images.  I have some sample code that should work but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

```
Bitmap[] Images = ReadAndScale(Width: 50, Height: 50);

int Width = 50;
int Height = 50;

double[,] Result = new int[50,50]

for (int i = 0 i < Images.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
  {
     for (int k = 0; k < Height; k++)
     {
         Result[j, k] += Images[i].GetPixel(j,k) == Color.White ? 0 
                         : 1.0 / (double)Images.Count;
     }
  }
}
```

At the end of these loops you have an array Result[] that contains the average value; > .5 is black otherwise the average is white.

Comment: What isn't working about it? You calculate the average result then what do you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think your general algorithm is fine, not really a way to make that "better".

The only way I see you could make it "better" would be to scrape more performance out of it, but do you need that?

The main perf issue I see is the use of GetPixel() as it is a relatively slow method.  Here is an example using unsafe code that should run much faster: [Unsafe Bitmap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2007/06/20/lost-column-2-unsafe-image-processing.aspx)

Don't let the word "unsafe" scare you, it just is the keyword for enabling true pointers in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make the images the inner loop, and break out as soon as you've guaranteed the average will be less than or greater than .5.  Not sure if that is really "better".